# JAVA 8 distinctByKey

Tags: java, java-8, lightweight-stream-api

```
public List<XYZ> getFilteredList(List<XYZ> l1) {
        return l1
                .stream()
                .filter(distinctByKey(XYZ::getName))
                .filter(distinctByKey(XYZ::getPrice))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

private static <T> Predicate<T> distinctByKey(Function<? super T, Object> 
 keyExtractor) {
        Map<Object,Boolean> seen = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
        return t -> seen.putIfAbsent(keyExtractor.apply(t), Boolean.TRUE) == null;
    }
```

Can anyone please help me,
What is the meaning of this line ------->
`return t -> seen.putIfAbsent(keyExtractor.apply(t), Boolean.TRUE) == null;`

Why is the lambda result compared to null?

Answer (score 1):

Your question revolves about the following:

```
return t -> seen.putIfAbsent(keyExtractor.apply(t),
                Boolean.TRUE) == null;
```

- first, the return returns the entire lambda (from t->.. onward).  It still references the created Map as a `closure` via `seen` even though the map itself is now out of scope.
- The `keyExtractor` will retrieve the key (either name or price) in your example via the setters provided as method references (`e.g. XYZ::getName`)
- `putIfAbsent` tries to add the boolean value `true` to the map for the supplied key (in this case, the `name` and `price` from the `keyExtractor`).  If the key was already present, it returns that value which would be `true`.  Since `true` is not equal to `null`, `false` is returned and the filter doesn't pass the value.  If the value was not there, null is returned.  Since `null == null` is true, `true` will be returned and the value passed thru the filter (i.e. it is thusfar distinct).

Here is an example of how this would work. This uses a simple record and only applying a filter on name.

```
record XYZ(String getName, String other){
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("[name=%s, other=%s]", getName, other);
    }
}
    
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<XYZ> l1 = List.of(
            new XYZ("A","B"),
            new XYZ("B","B"),
            new XYZ("B","C"),
            new XYZ("B","D"),
            new XYZ("C","B"));

    
    Object ob =
            l1.stream().filter(distinctByKey(XYZ::getName))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
    System.out.println(ob);
}
```

prints

```
[[name=A, other=B], [name=B, other=B], [name=C, other=B]]
```

Notice that only the first Name of `B` was allowed thru the filter, the others were blocked.

```
private static <T> Predicate<T>
        distinctByKey(Function<? super T, Object> keyExtractor) {
    Map<Object, Boolean> seen = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    return t -> seen.putIfAbsent(keyExtractor.apply(t),
            Boolean.TRUE) == null;
}
```

Comment: Thank you @WJS for the useful explanation. Can you please give me an Idea on how I can unit test this function (distinctByKey())?
Also, why do we have <T> before Predicate<T>? 
Thanks.

Comment: The second question is best answered in the section of [Generic Methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/methods.html) in the Java Tutorials.  As far as Junit testing goes, one way would be to have a test that filters a predefined data structure (e.g a `list`) and returns the contents.  Those contents would then be compared to another `list` of the expected results and would either return true or false.

Comment: Thank you so much @WJS for the valuable answer!